# Error When Trying to Run MDW Data Collector

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, configuration, management-data-warehouse

I have SQL Server Management Data Warehouse (MDW) set up across multiple instances, all in the same way with the same accounts and permissions.

On one server I get an error when trying to run the data collectors. The error states that SSIS packages for the data collectors are missing. True enough, when I check `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages`, 8 packages relating to collecting and uploading are missing.

In addition, system logs showed the following error:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {FDC3723D-1588-4BA3-92D4-42C430735D7D}  and APPID 
>   {83B33982-693D-4824-B42E-7196AE61BB05}

Does anyone know a fix for this? It is really odd, since all my other instances are running the data collectors without issues. I am running SQL Server 2012 and my host MDW database is on a remote server. But again, all other MDW instances collect and upload without error.

I saw [SQL Server 2012 Integration Services and DCOM Permissions](http://klonkers.blogspot.ca/2013/09/sql-server-2012-integration-services.html) by John Veazey, which has a common fix for people but it didn't work for me. The sys log error went away, but the error when running data collection persists.

Answer (score 3):

So apparently network packet size setting in **sp_configure** was changed up to 32kb when it needed to be under 16kb. Once I reconfigured the setting, the jobs ran successfully. Who would have thought...